FirebaseAnalytics can't find FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework
I want to upgrade FirebaseAnalytics from version 8.15.0 to version 10.24.0, I installation FirebaseAnalytics with CocoaPods.
After successful pod install, I found that the FirebaseAnalytics.xcframework file cannot be found. Of course, I can't search for FIRAnalytics.h
I have been stuck in this for a long time and I hope to get someone's help. Thank you.
8.15.0
enter image description here
10.24.0
enter image description here

Hi, Did you find any solution for this?

Sorry, I just saw it. I changed ‘pod 'FirebaseAnalytics' ‘ to ‘pod 'Firebase/Analytics'’ can resolve this problem, I'm not very clear about the specific reasons either
